# How to setup OAuth 2.0 server using loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to setup an OAuth 2.0 Server using Loopback using a package called loopback-component-oauth2

The documentation is here :
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/OAuth+2.0#OAuth2.0-UsingtheOAuth2component

But it is very unclear, what models should i create and what rest endpoint should be defined?

Please help!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's important to note that the documentation might be outdated:

> After IBM’s acquisition of StrongLoop, we have integrated
>   strong-gateway with the latest product offering from IBM called API
>   Connect.

In any case, if you need some directions on how the server is set to provide OAUTH 2 authentications you should look at the following git project and pay a close attention to the following:

- *strong-gateway/server/server.js* - gives you an idea of which modules and methods to create inside your server script.
- *strong-gateway/test/* * - has a bunch of scripts that shows how it is used in an authorization context.

Git project using OAuth2.0 with the StrongLoop API Gateway: https://github.com/strongloop-archive/strong-gateway